# How to schedule an item to run on specific Day of the month given Start Date

Tags: c#

I have a schedule event that I want to run on every specific day of the month given a start date. So a start Date for example 06/27/2019 is Thursday. I want to run the next schedule of Thursday 07/25/2019 till an end date for example 09/30/2021

```
    public class BusinessWeekDays
    {
        public DateTime Monday;
        public DateTime Sunday;
    }            

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var StartDateMonth = DateTime.Parse("06/27/2019");
        var SeriesEndDate = DateTime.Parse("09/30/2019");

        var months = new List<BusinessWeekDays>();

        var m = StartDateMonth.Day == 1
            ? StartDateMonth
            : StartDateMonth.AddDays(-(StartDateMonth.Day - 
     1)).AddMonths(+1);
        m = m.Date;

        for (;;)
        {
            var e = m.AddMonths(+1).AddDays(-1);
            if (e.Date > SeriesEndDate.Date) break;
            if (BusinessDays(StartDateMonth, SeriesEndDate) != 0)
            {
                months.Add(new BusinessWeekDays
                {
                    Monday = m, Sunday
                        = e
                });
                m = m.AddMonths(+1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get something that executes on the nth (some)day of every month?

Comment: What do you want to do about Feb 29?

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html

Comment: I don't need a schedular. I can do that windows schedular. I just want to calculate recurring dates and insert all those dates in the database. What I want is for example Starting date 06/27/2019 is Thursday. the following month of July 2019 should end Thursday, August 2019 Thursday till Series end on 09/30/2021

Comment: Basically what I want is the last Thursday of every month between the start and end dates